# Type or namespace ActionExecutingContext or ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello Suddenly my mvc application started giving exceptions :

```
rror    36  The type or namespace name 'ActionExecutingContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\TMM\Desktop\04.09\BEAWEB_WITH_LANG - Copy\MvcBeaWeb\MvcBeaWeb\Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs   18  48  MvcBeaWeb
Error   22  The type or namespace name 'ActionFilterAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\TMM\Desktop\04.09\BEAWEB_WITH_LANG - Copy\MvcBeaWeb\MvcBeaWeb\Filters\NoCacheAttribute.cs  9   36  MvcBeaWeb
Error   30  The type or namespace name 'ActionFilterAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\TMM\Desktop\04.09\BEAWEB_WITH_LANG - Copy\MvcBeaWeb\MvcBeaWeb\Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs   12  63  MvcBeaWeb
Error   39  The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\TMM\Desktop\04.09\BEAWEB_WITH_LANG - Copy\MvcBeaWeb\MvcBeaWeb\Controllers\AccountsController.cs    24  16  MvcBeaWeb
```

I even re installed visual studio 2012!

Best Regards,

Comment: Are all your references still present and correct?

Comment: Yes that's the curious thing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mika's answer worked for me. What the hell was in that windows update??! "What you can do is just in the reference folder of your mvc web application - delete the reference to System.Web.Mvc and then again - add the reference to System.Web.Mvc. That solved my problem! And yes the problem is because of the updates"

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all the references to System.Web.Mvc within your solution. Just delete them and add the new 4.0.0.1 version.

Also in the properties change copy local to true.